# Make Labview wait until the instrument has finished running the script (Keithley 2612A)

Tags: labview

I load a script on keithley 2612a and then I want labview to wait until the instrument has finished running the script. I thought of trying to set a digio bit and check its value in a while loop. I have the following code in the beginning and end of the script respectively, but the value of the bit doesn't change when i read it.

```
digio.writeprotect = 0
digio.writebit(1, 0)
        .
        .
        .
smub.source.output = OFF
digio.writebit(1, 1)
```

The following link is an image from the while loop where I continuously read the value of bit 1.
http://pasteboard.co/EUTDffY.png

**EDIT**
I have added a delay for each measurement and I think that this causes a timeout or something. Maybe this is why?

Comment: If you are suspecting a timeout error, why don't you have a closer look at the **error terminal** of your keithley vi? Did you try debugging your code step by step?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use a delay in your while loop where you continuously read the value of bit 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm absolutely baffled as to why keithley have decided to write a new language for this device.  Why not use SCPI.

The SCPI standard provides the *OPC? query that you can use to ensure the instrument has completed all operations before your program continues.

I think you need to discover what the equivalent of *OPC is in the new language.

The following example is in the manual:

**Calling a function without parameters**

When the command to call a script function is sent without parameters, input value fields and
messages will appear on the display to prompt the operator to input the parameters using the front
panel controls.
The following command will call the SourceVMeasureI function and then require operator
interaction:
PulseVMeasureI()
After sending the above command, the Series 2600A display will prompt the operator to input the
following parameters from the front panel:
• Enter BIAS voltage.
• Enter PULSE (level) voltage.
• Enter pulse ON time.
• Enter pulse OFF time.
• Enter number of pulses (points).
After the operator keys in each parameter and presses the ENTER key (or the navigation wheel),
the display will proceed to the next input prompt. After the last parameter (number of pulses) is
entered, the test will continue.
The following message will be displayed when the test is finished:
PulseVMeasureI
Test complete.